# please help, trying to get data from another class

Tags: android, xml

http://pastebin.com/2vhnNJpA

Could someone have a look at this code for me and help me out with trying to display data from another `class`

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bill_periodFrom);
tv.setText(itemisedbill.getperiodFrom());
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bill_periodTo);
tv.setText(itemisedbill.getperiodTo());
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bill_cost);
tv.setText(itemisedbill.getcost());
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bill_amountUsed);
tv.setText(itemisedbill.getamountUsed());
```

That's a small part of the code I'm having trouble with, eclipse says that itemisedbill in null

Comment: please post the whole code...

Comment: have you check that `ParseitemisedbillFromXML(arg0[0]);` returns something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FirstActivity**

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
i.putExtra("numbers", "number");
startActivity(i);
```

**SecondActivty**

```
//in oncreate method
String number= getIntent().getStringExtra("numbers");
```

Or further reading u have to read this tutorial:-

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HuR3MgbH

http://pastebin.com/LjG1cr5V

http://pastebin.com/KYWjZ5g5

http://pastebin.com/sY3YuYFk

http://pastebin.com/vi3c2Xyz

http://pastebin.com/NtgH1vdn --- that's the rest of my code, I think I've tried to do your method and it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to read again [Android AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)... You make mistakes with parameters.

Comment: Could you say what the mistakes are?

Comment: No there is no mistake with parameter, I apologize... I think your problem is the variable **bill** in the onCreate() method, you must Log your **bills bill = (bills)intent.getSerializableExtra("bill");**. If it's null, all your AsynkTask will fail because of the **bill.getItemisedBill()** in the URL suffix

Comment: I'm pretty sure bill has data inside of it because I changed the code in my first post to have a look to see if it was working

Comment: Is your **getItemisedBill()** return a String ?

Comment: Indeed. Here's my code for all the other classes pastebin.com/HuR3MgbH pastebin.com/LjG1cr5V pastebin.com/KYWjZ5g5 pastebin.com/sY3YuYFk pastebin.com/vi3c2Xyz pastebin.com/NtgH1vdn

Comment: Put a **Log.i("URL SENT", arg0[0]);** before **return ParseitemisedbillFromXML(arg0[0]);** and look in DDMS if the URL is correct... Or not !

Comment: Yeah the URL is fine, I'm sure it's something to do with tv.setText(itemisedbill.getperiodFrom());

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?

Comment: How do you know **itemisedbill** is null ? Where do you find this information ?